# Python Dataframe: Shuffle group of rows

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, dataframe

What is the best way to shuffle a group of rows in a data frame? Need this for a shuffled train set of the model.

For example, shuffle every 10 rows as a separate group or have some logical condition to create separate groups and shuffle them as a group.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new column with the index you're grouping on, you could do something like:

```
groups = [df.sample(frac=1) for _, df in df.groupby('index_to_group_on')]
return pandas.concat(groups)
```

If, for example, you want to shuffle every group of 10 rows, you could create this index via:

```
df['group_of_ten'] = numpy.arange(len(df)/10)
```

If you're trying to do cross validation, you can look into scikit-learn's `train_test_split`: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Probably you misunderstood my request. This is an example of what / how I want to shuffle (shuffle of the groups of 3 rows)3 rows shuffle:

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
     0   1   2   3
0    0   0   0   0
1    1   1   1   1
2    2   2   2   2
3    3   3   3   3
4    4   4   4   4
5    5   5   5   5
6    6   6   6   6
7    7   7   7   7
8    8   8   8   8
9    9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10
11  11  11  11  11


Shuffled: Out[18]:
     0   1   2   3
0    0   0   0   0
1    1   1   1   1
2    2   2   2   2
3    9   9   9   9
4   10  10  10  10
5   11  11  11  11

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways too, one way may be using `shuffle` from `sklearn`. You can slice the `n` rows that you want to shuffle and `append` remaining other rows using `.append` to the result of shuffled rows.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# if df is the dataframe to then:
n = 10 # number of rows to shuffle
shuffled_df = shuffle(df[:n]).append(df[n:])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is - create a column which identifies the group and then group by that column, followed by a random shuffle of each group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['group_id'] = np.arange(df.shape[0]) // 10  # // is integer division in python3, won't work in python2
shuffled_groups = [v.drop(['group_id'], axis=1).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) for k, v in df.groupby('group_id')]
```